# Curl Header Information

Tags: http, curl

I am trying to upload data to a webserver using curl. I have analyzed the data sent to the server, from a browser, using wireshark, shown below:

```
POST /cgi-bin/upload.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.22
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2637
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://192.168.1.22
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryn1sckmiVOVfCwUMQ
Referer: http://192.168.1.22/upload.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I looked at the webpage the browser accesses to upload the information, shown below:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://192.168.1.22/cgi-bin/upload.cgi">
File to upload: 
<input type="file" name="theupload"><br>
Should it be updated?<input type="checkbox" name="configuration"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
</form>
```

I attempted to use:

```
curl --referer http://192.168.1.22/upload.html -F theupload=@file1.xml -F config=on http://192.168.1.22:80/cgi-bin/upload.cgi
```

My output was

```
POST /cgi-bin/upload.cgi HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
Host: 192.168.1.22
Accept: */*
Referer: http://192.168.1.22/upload.html
Content-Length: 2650
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------fd126312049d1f47
```

The server returns **HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed**.
I am just learning curl, and I am unsure of what to do. Do i need to emulate the header of the browser command as closely as possible? or is the boundary what is probably throwing it off?
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `curl -H "Expect:" ...`

Comment: It worked, great. Thanks. Why would the "Expects" string default?

Comment: @user2558056 curl uses [14.20 Expect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header by default as it is http 1.1 client and before sending body ask server "do you accept it?", web server or proxy in your case do not understand this behaviour